# Number of inversions using merge sort

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting, mergesort

I wrote this code to get the number of inversions using `merge_sort`, but I am not getting the correct output. Can someone tell me why is it giving the wrong output?

```
def merge(B,C):  # B,C are sorted
  D = list()
  count = 0
  # empty list to get the merged list
  while (B != []) and (C != []):  # breaks if any one of B or C becomes empty

    b = B[0]  # to get first element of B
    print("b",b)
    c = C[0]  # to get first element of C
    print("c",c)
    
    if b<=c:
      B.remove(b)  # if b<c remove b from B and add to D
      D.append(b)
    else:
      C.remove(c)  # if b>c remove c from C and add to D
      D.append(c)
      count += 1
      print("count_in_merge",count)

  # now if either one of B or C has become empty so while loop is exited
  # so we can add remaining elements of B and C as it is to D as they are
  # already sorted
  if B != []:                                       
    for i in B:
      D.append(i)
  
  if C != []:
     for i in C:
      D.append(i)

  return D, count 

def sort_and_num(A):
  if len(A) == 1:
    return A,0

  m = len(A) // 2
    
  B,count_b = sort_and_num(A[0:m])
  C,count_c = sort_and_num(A[m:])
    
  A_,count = merge(B,C)
  count += (count_b + count_c)
  
  return A_, count
```

When I run:

```
A = [ 9, 8 ,7, 3, 2, 1] 
A_,c = sort_and_num(A)
print(A_,c)
```

The output is:

```
[1, 2, 3, 7, 8, 9] 9
```

But the output should have been

```
[1, 2, 3, 7, 8, 9] 15
```

On the other hand, if I input :

```
A = [3,1,2,4] 
A_, count = sort_and_num(A)
print(A_, count)
```

the output is:

```
[1,2,3,4 ] 3
```

which is correct. Where is it going wrong?

Comment: what do you count as an inversion?

Comment: @SdahSean the number of times 2 elements interchanged their position to make the input array closer to being sorted.

Comment: Where have you defined ```sort_and_num()```?

Comment: @abhinavmathur the sort_num was supposed to be sort_and_num. I corrected it. (The issue is still the same.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some issues in your code:

- to remove the first element of a list, you should use `pop()`, not `remove()`
- the number of inversions when you take the element from `C` is `len(B)`, not `1`.
- you should add the number of inversions from each half and that of the merge phase
- the intial test in `sort_and_num` should also test for an empty list and return it with a count of 0.

Here is a modified version:

```
def merge(B, count_b, C, count_c):  # B,C are sorted
   D = []
   count = count_b + count_c
   # empty list to get the merged list
   while (B != []) and (C != []):  # breaks if any one of B or C becomes empty
      if B[0] <= C[0]:
         D.append(B.pop())  # if b<=c remove b from B and add it to D
      else:
         D.append(C.pop())  # if b>c remove c from C and add it to D
         count += len(B)    # moving c before all remaining elements of B

  # now if either one of B or C has become empty so while loop is exited
  # so we can add remaining elements of B and C as it is to D as they are
  # already sorted
  for i in B:
     D.append(i)
  
  for i in C:
     D.append(i)

  return D, count 

def sort_and_num(A):
   if len(A) <= 1:
      return A,0

   m = len(A) // 2
    
   B,count_b = sort_and_num(A[:m])
   C,count_c = sort_and_num(A[m:])
    
   return merge(B, count_b, C, count_c)
```

Answer (score 1):

In this code fragment:

```
else:
    C.remove(c)  # if b>c remove c from C and add to D
    D.append(c)
    count += 1
```

you should update `count` by length of the rest part of `B` list

```
    count += len(B)
```

because moving an element from the right part may "correct" many inversions at once.

Also note that chosen implementation is rather ineffective due to instant removing elements from the lists.